# Get file type from windows registry in c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to display file type of given filename (based on extension) using `AssocQueryKey()` API function.
The problem is thar return wrong `HKEY` value sometimes. For example the following function works correctly on win 7 ultimate x64, but fails for some extensions like ".mp3" on my win xp x86 machine (other extensions works though).
Even when "succeeded" and returns S_OK, `GetLastError()` is 1008 ALWAYS after `AssocQueryKey()` call:

```
// Return STL string representation of file type from windows registry
stlstring GetFileTypeFromRegistry(const stlstring& m_filename)
{
 CRegKey reg;
 HKEY key = {0};
 stlstring s;
 //Get file extension
 LPCTSTR fExt = PathFindExtension(m_filename.c_str());
 if(AssocQueryKey(NULL, ASSOCKEY_CLASS, fExt, TEXT(""),  &key) != S_OK)
  DisplayError(_T("AssocQueryKey != S_OK"), GetLastError());
 else
  DisplayError(_T("AssocQueryKey == S_OK"), GetLastError());

 if(reg.Open ( key, NULL, KEY_QUERY_VALUE) != ERROR_SUCCESS){
  reg.Close();
  DisplayError((LPTSTR)fExt);
  return s;
 }
 //DWORD out = 0;
 /*WCHAR *h = new WCHAR[1024];
 ZeroMemory(h, sizeof(h));
 AssocQueryStringByKey(0, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, NULL, h, &out);
 //MessageBox(0,_T("gbtbb"),h,MB_OK);
 delete[] h;*/
 ULONG m_sz = 256;
 //if( reg.QueryStringValue(NULL, NULL, &m_sz) == ERROR_SUCCESS){

  TCHAR *m_regstring = new TCHAR[m_sz + 1];
   if(reg.QueryStringValue(NULL, m_regstring, &m_sz) == ERROR_SUCCESS){
    //DisplayError(_T(""));
    s += m_regstring;
   /*delete[] m_regstring; m_regstring = NULL;
   reg.Close();
    return s;*/
   } else {
    DisplayError(_T("CRegKey::QueryStringValue()"), GetLastError());
   }
   s += m_regstring;
   delete[] m_regstring; m_regstring = NULL;
   reg.Close();
   return s;
 /*}
 reg.Close();
 return s;*/
}
```

Any ideas on this ?? This function is from a DLL which is loaded by windows explorer, implementing `IQueryInfo::GetInfoTip()` if that matters.

Comment: When you say it "fails for some extensions like '.mp3'", you mean that it returns `S_OK` but the `HKEY` isn't for the correct registry location?  Note that checking the value of `GetLastError()` when no error is returned is meaningless - the last error code is often set incidentally by functions called by the the API you call.  Its value is meaningless unless you get an indication that an error has occurred (in other words, APIs that succeed are not required to maintain the original value of the last error or to set it to 0).

Comment: NULL for the 1st argument makes little sense.  A definition of failure is required here.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `GetLastError` for functions that return the error code directly. The MSDN page for [`AssocQueryKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773468%28VS.85%29.aspx) says "Returns S_OK if successful, or a COM error value otherwise.", which means you already get the error code in the return value.

If you just want to get the file type information, there's a much simpler solution: [`SHGetFileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179%28VS.85%29.aspx). It's really simple to use, like this:

```
SHFILEINFO shfi;
SHGetFileInfo(filename, 0, &shfi, sizeof(shfi), SHGFI_TYPENAME | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES);
// shfi.szTypeName now contains the file type string of the given filename
```